# Plotting multiple variables from a csv file in the same graph. R

Tags: r

I have a csv file ("data.csv") with several columns. My dependent variable is J and my independent variables are S1, S2, S3 and S4.

```
J  S1  S2  S3  S4  Z
1   4   5   3   2  0
2  12  11  34  44  0
3  12  15  22  21  1
4  10   9  10  11  1
```

I have managed to plot J and S1:

```
Reg.data <- read.csv ("C: \\ Users \\ data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ';')
Library (ggplot2)
Qplot (data = reg.data, x = J, y = mean(S1), color = "red")
```

Now, I would like to plot (in the same graph) all my independent variables S1, S2, S3, S4 in different colours. I've tried (and I've searched in the forum) but I can not do it.

I would also like to know how to plot three axes: variable J, variables S (on the same axis) and covariable Z.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being sure I have correctly understood the question, you could try the following:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)

dat1 <- fread('J  S1  S2  S3  S4  Z
              1   4   5   3   2  0
              2  12  11  34  44  0
              3  12  15  22  21  1
              4  10   9  10  11  1')

temp <- melt(dat1, id.vars = c("J", "Z"))

ggplot(temp, aes(x = J, y = value, color = variable, shape = as.factor(Z))) +
  geom_point()
```

This gives you the following plot:
[image]

One limitation that this approach has is that I have assumed that Z is a variable with discrete values (and a small number of discrete values at that). If this is not the case you can map it to alpha perhaps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm gonna try this. But my data file is much more heavy, so... is there any way to do something similar but from the csv file? I mean, not from a table.

Comment: No R loads everything in memory. So you will have to read the CSV file and store it in a data table / data frame...

Comment: That being said, if you have a file that you can load in memory (as in you have enough RAM for it) data table and ggplot are quite efficient :)

Comment: What if I'd like to select only one level of Z. I mean, if I'd like to represent only data points for Z=0?

Comment: Well you can subset your plot dataset for example `temp_new = temp[Z==0]`

Answer (score 0):

I ever so slightly "extended" the [very helpful example above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43938522/7311767) to read a CSV format data file (above) that is entitled 'exampledata.csv' and it looks like the following:

```
J,S1,S2,S3,S4,Z
1,4,5,3,2,0
2,12,11,34,44,0
3,12,15,22,21,1
4,10,9,10,11,1
```

To generate the very same plot that reads this CSV file, I used the following:

```
require(data.table)
require(ggplot2)
dat1 <- read.csv(file = "exampledata.csv")
temp <- melt(dat1, id.vars = c("J", "Z"))
ggplot(temp, aes(x = J, y = value, color = variable, shape = as.factor(Z))) +
geom_point(size = 3)
```

PS - I admittedly made the data points a bit larger because the eyes aren't as great as they used to be...

If you wish to use more data to create a bit more interesting plot, please use the following longer version of the CSV data file that is entitled 'exampledata.csv' (above):

```
J,S1,S2,S3,S4,Z
1,9,12,13,15,0
2,12,11,18,24,0
3,12,15,22,21,1
4,10,9,10,11,1
5,15,11,14,17,0
6,11,8,12,14,0
7,13,10,19,15,0
8,11,14,15,17,1
9,16,17,14,12,0
10,13,11,14,12,1
```